# Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in C:\Program Files.... on line 223

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting Fatal error (Location mentioned) in following code

```
try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername1;dbname=Userdb", $username1, $password1);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //Set PDO error mode to exception.
    //Executing query
    $q=$dbc->exec(" UPDATE  USertable
                SET     username='$username', password='$password'
                WHERE   id=1");
    echo $q->rowCount()."Records UPDATED successfully"; //LINE 223 ERROR IN THIS LINE
    echo "Step 4 Successfull";

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $q. $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    die();
}
$dbc = $q = Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$dbc->rowCount()
```

if your query is getting executed propely

```
$q=$dbc->exec(" UPDATE  USertable
                SET     username='$username', password='$password'
                WHERE   id=1");
```

else use

`$conn` for both  `$conn ->exec()` and `$conn ->rowCount()`

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `$dbc` is not an instance of an object.
It's look a copy/paste error.
Update your query to execute on an instance of an object

```
$q=$conn->exec(" UPDATE  USertable
            SET     username='$username', password='$password'
            WHERE   id=1");
```

Also you should use prepare/execute function for update query,not exec()